# Seeding table in KnexJS foreign key constraint

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

I am building a NodeJS API backend and using Knex to handle DB migrations et al.

I have 3 tables: `stalls`, `markets` and `bookings`

In my `bookings` table I want to reference the `id` column from both the `stalls` and `markets` tables.

I have setup my `bookings` migration as follows:-

```
    exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable("bookings", table => {
    table.increments("id");
    table.string("firstName");
    table.string("lastName");
    table.string("address");
    table.string("phoneNumber");
    table.string("emailAddress");
    table
      .integer("marketDateId")
      .references("id")
      .inTable("markets");
    table
      .integer("stallTypeId")
      .references("id")
      .inTable("stalls");
    table.boolean("clothesRail");
    table.string("businessName");
    table.boolean("businessInsurance");
    table.string("items");
  });
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable("bookings");
};
```

Stalls:

```
    exports.up = (knex, Promise) => {
  return knex.schema.createTable("stalls", table => {
    table.increments("id");
    table.string("stallType");
  });
};

exports.down = (knex, Promise) => {
  return knex.schema.dropTable("stalls");
};
```

Markets:

```
exports.up = (knex, Promise) => {
  return knex.schema.createTable("markets", table => {
    table.increments("id");
    table.string("marketDate");
  });
};

exports.down = (knex, Promise) => {
  return knex.schema.dropTable("markets");
};
```

I have seeded the `stalls` and `markets` tables with some dummy data, but when I try to seed the `bookings` table using the below seed file:

`bookings.js`

```
exports.seed = (knex, Promise) =>
  knex("bookings")
    .del()
    .then(() =>
      knex("bookings").insert([
        {
          firstName: "Test",
          lastName: "Tester",
          phoneNumber: "07123 123456",
          emailAddress: "test@lb-dev.io",
          marketDateId: "7",
          stallTypeId: "7",
          clothesRail: false,
          items: "Testing Stuff"
        },
        {
          firstName: "Test",
          lastName: "Testington",
          phoneNumber: "07123 123456",
          emailAddress: "test@lb-dev.io",
          marketDateId: "8",
          stallTypeId: "8",
          clothesRail: false,
          businessName: "TestCrafts",
          items: "Testing Stuff"
        },
        {
          firstName: "Test",
          lastName: "Tester",
          phoneNumber: "07123 123456",
          emailAddress: "test@lb-dev.io",
          marketDateId: "9",
          stallTypeId: "9",
          clothesRail: true,
          businessName: "TestBusiness",
          businessInsurance: true,
          items: "Testing Stuff"
        }
      ])
    );
```

I get the following error on running `knex seed:run`

`update or delete on table "markets" violates foreign key constraint "bookings_marketdateid_foreign" on table "bookings"`

Comment: I am having this exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `marketDateId` field of the `bookings` table was defined to be a [foreign key](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) that references a field in some other table. This was to ensure referential integrity. See this related [postgres tutorial page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/tutorial-fk.html) for an example.

Your code must therefore ensure that it only tries to assign `marketDateId` values that exist in a row of that other table.

Comment: So as long as a referenced row exists, it will not be possible to receive this error?